# Setar "currentTime" em áudio no HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5

Preciso tocar partes de algumas músicas em algo que estou fazendo. Por exemplo:

```
var audio = new Audio('musica.mp3');
audio.play();

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if(audio.currentTime) {
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 15;
        audio.play();
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
},100);
```

Eu tentei fazer dessa forma, mas não funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve aguardar até que o arquivo de audio tenha carregado para aplicar o `currentTime`, exemplo:

```
var audio = new Audio('musica.mp3');
audio.play();

audio.addEventListener('canplay', function() {;
    this.currentTime = 15;
    this.play();
});
```

Ai se você quiser um loop dentro de tempo pode aplicar no evento:

```
audio.addEventListener('canplay', function() {;
    this.currentTime = 15;
    this.play();
    setInterval(function () {
        this.currentTime = 15;
        this.play();
    }.bind(this), 100);
});
```

Bom lembrar que seu audio deve estar no DOM pra ele tocar, exemplo:

```
document.body.appendChild(audio);
```

De uma olhada no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xp8kP/1/) que fiz pra vc.

Mas se você quer fazer um loop na sua música em um momento especifico, não recomendo que use o `setInterval` pois ele não vai garantir o efeito correto, no caso o ideal é que você utilize o evento `timeupdate` então seu código ficaria assim:

```
audio.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
    this.currentTime = 15;
    this.play();
});

audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    if(this.currentTime >= 18) {
        this.currentTime = 15;
    }
});
```

O `setInterval` é um evento de tempo do javascript que vai ser disparado de forma enfileirada conforme a disponibilidade do javascript, o que pode levar ele a cortar a música mais tarde que o desejado e em seguida mais cedo ficando com comportamento bem estranho. O segundo exemplo está disponível também [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/Xp8kP/2/).